# How to add rows to table in one HTML page by asking for data to be added into rows from another HTML page (may be using "prompt" & javascripts)?

Tags: javascript, html

I used following code:

**Form1.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Table of Data</title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="POST">

<table border="1" id="tblQuery">
<tr>
   <th>Query</th>
   <th>Answer</th>
   <th>Data Type</th>
   <th>Screen No.</th>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td><input type="text"/></td>
   <td>Textbox</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Gender</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Male<br><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" />Female</td>
   <td>Radio Buttons</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Qualification</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="qualification" value="graduate" />Graduate<br><input type="checkbox" name="qualification" value="post graduate" />Post Graduate</td>
   <td>Checkbox</td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>City</td>
   <td><select>
      <option value="new_delhi">New Delhi</option>
      <option value="mumbai">Mumbai</option>
      <option value="kolkata">Kolkata</option>
      <option value="chennai">Chennai</option>
      </select></td>
   <td>Select List</td>
   <td>4</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td>Academic Record</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Add Table" onclick="addTable.html" /></td>
   <td>Table</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td><input type="button" value="Edit" /><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td>
</tr>

</table>

<br>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

**Form2.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Action</title>

<script src="scripts/newQuery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<input type="button" value="Add Query" onclick="openPage()" />

&nbsp; &nbsp;

<input type="button" value="Create Metafile" />

</body>

</html>
```

Later, I added both the pages to an `"index.html"` file using `"frameset"` element as follows:

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Main Application case Study</title>
</head>

<frameset rows="75%, *">
   <frame src="Form.html" />
   <frame src="Form2.html" />
</frameset>

</html>
```

Now if I open the `"index.html"` page & click on `"Add Query"` button, I would get a `"prompt"` message that would ask me my Query to be added & i'll add it to `"Form1.html"` page.

The problem i'm facing here is that, when i submit my query to be added to the table, the query is actually submitted to `"Form2.html"` page, as the `"prompt"` is coded at that page. But I need to add a row to `"Form1.html"`.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Hire an actual developer and drop the frames? Ajax is likely what you really want here

Comment: oh... actually, its my college project... I can't hire someone to achieve this.....actually, I was looking forward for some help from "StackOverflow.com".....I thought I might find someone here more talented than me & a champ in HTML & JavaScript coding....

Comment: Aha - homework...  Make an effort and we will help you. You will need a server process. What is in newQuery.js ?

Comment: It's just a functio that opens a pop up window which asks user to enter Query to be added to the table.
I used it as an alternate option for "prompt".
It is as follows:


function openPage()
{
   window.open("newQuery.html", "_blank", "width=330, height=150, resizable=yes");
}

Comment: So if it opens from the same domain, use opener.document.... How does the table look after you add something?

Comment: actually nothing is being added to the table... :(
That's what I actually wish to achieve.... & that's what actually I'm looking help for...

Answer (score 0):

You are making your life much harder than necessary.

You want to open a page that opens a page which does something like

http://www.dzone.com/snippets/add-rows-html-table

```
function addRow(table,content,morecontent,evenmorecontent) {
     var tabBody=table.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
     var row=document.createElement("TR");
     var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
     var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
     var cell3 = document.createElement("TD");
     var textnode1=document.createTextNode(content);
     var textnode2=document.createTextNode(morecontent);
     var textnode3=document.createTextNode(evenmorecontent);
     cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
     cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
     cell3.appendChild(textnode3);
     row.appendChild(cell1);
     row.appendChild(cell2);
     row.appendChild(cell3);
     tabBody.appendChild(row);
}
var table = opener.opener.document.getElementById("tblQuery");
addRow(table,"cell1 content","cell2 content","cell3 content");
```